# How to fix 'Failed to start unknown module mod_offline_push' when starting ejabberd 19.05 by docker

Tags: docker, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I inserted a parameter named "auth_use_cache: false" into conf/ejabberd.yml. Then I restarted the image "ejabberd:19.05" using docker-compose. As a result, it failed to start the docker image whose status is always "UP xx seconds". Then, I checked the log of the image and found that the following information is displayed.

```html
==> /usr/local/var/log/ejabberd/error.log <==
2021-09-18 03:42:41.550 [critical] <0.254.0>@gen_mod:start_module:228 Failed to start unknown module mod_offline_push, did you mean mod_offline_riak? Hint: make sure there is no typo and mod_offline_push.beam exists inside either /usr/local/lib/ejabberd-19.05/ebin or /opt/ejabberd/.ejabberd-modules directory
03:42:41.550 [critical] Failed to start unknown module mod_offline_push, did you mean mod_offline_riak? Hint: make sure there is no typo and mod_offline_push.beam exists inside either /usr/local/lib/ejabberd-19.05/ebin or /opt/ejabberd/.ejabberd-modules directory
```

So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: no idea since you haven't shared anything with us

Comment: Please share how you start the docker container. Share the compose file and the configuration, you use to start the container. Otherwise we can not help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I inserted a parameter named "auth_use_cache: false" into conf/ejabberd.yml

Where in the file did you insert that parameter, exactly?

If you remove that option, does ejabberd work correctly again?

> Failed to start unknown module mod_offline_push,

That module isn't included in ejabberd... did you install that module yourself?

Why is that module mentioned in ejabberd.yml, did you add it?

> Hint: make sure there is no typo and mod_offline_push.beam exists inside either /usr/local/lib/ejabberd-19.05/ebin or /opt/ejabberd/.ejabberd-modules directory

Does that file exist in any of those paths?

Comment: Firstly，I insert the parameter under `LDAP authentication` part in the file. To be honest, the value of the parameter `auth_method` is `external`  in the `AUTHENTICATION` part of file `conf/ejabberd.yml` and I never change it.

Comment: After I removed this parameter, ejabberd also doesn't work.    The module "mod_offline_push" is always in the docker deployment folder, and I have never changed this module.   The ejabberd docker image does delete some files during the down process, which may be the problem of error reporting.

Comment: I will check the exist these files and the reason of disappear. And I will also look for other problems. Thank you very much!